# R script/Survey data: Find sibling and record when that sibling is <=1 year old

Tags: r, survey

I would like to find a child's sibling(s) in survey data, check if it has ANY sibling whose age is <= 1 year, and store the result (1,0).

Here is my data:

| cluster | house_number | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 1 | 21 | 4 |
| 1 | 21 | 1 |
| 2 | 22 | 0 |
| 2 | 36 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |

I thought of looking for the match between cluster and house_number, and then check the age. But when there is a match how can you check for each child's siblings age and store the result (when it has at least one sibling <= 1 year of age). So you end up with this:

| cluster | house_number | age | sibling_age1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 21 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 21 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 36 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this :

```
# let's call your dataframe : data

# we create a new column called sibling_age on the condition of the age column
# and we use the ifelse function
# the first value represents the if argument
# the second value represents the else argument

data$sibling_age = ifelse(data$age>1,1,0)


# I hope that this is what you were looking for.
```